# How to use common dependencies in different clojurescript projects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clojurescript, leiningen, reagent

I wrote a clojurescript project. It is a reagent component. Now i want to use this component in other clojurescript project. That is what i do: I compiled my cljs project and then i put a result compiled file to js folder in other project. Further i require that file from index.html. At the end i invoke my component from cljs file

```
(.slider-view (.-views js/swipe) (clj->js [[:p "1"]
                                           [:p "2"]
                                           [:p "3"]]))
```

and it works. But i have a question. My project and project where i connect my component have common requirements. For example React and ReactDOM. How to exclude this two references from my project and then connect it from another project? Is there alternative approaches? For example require cljs namespace from another cljs project directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you could prevent JavaScript libraries from being included twice, you will still have huge chunks of the ClojureScript standard library compiled in twice.  As you suggested, you will want to put your first project on the classpath of your second project (by adding it to your project.clj or equivalent) and then include that namespace directly.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Justin's quite correct answer...

What you describe is exactly the normal ClojureScript dependency relationship. In this case, the dependency is something you have created, rather than someone else's existing library, but it is still the same situation.

There is one important subtlety to note. You may want to develop both of your projects simultaneously. This may seem tricky, since dependencies normally require a version number, deploying, and all the rest of the heavy lifting that is just too painful for quick development.

Fortunately, the standard ClojureScript tooling offers a solution to this, called the Leiningen checkouts directory, which works by letting you put a symlink to your dependency inside your main project's directory.

Details are in the [checkout-dependencies](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#checkout-dependencies) section of the [Leiningen](https://leiningen.org/) documentation; or just web search for "Clojure checkouts", if that ever decays.

As you get further into these techniques, you may hit some more subtle problems involving the Figwheel tooling. When you reach that stage, this [article](https://github.com/deg/clojure-then-you-think/wiki/Checkouts-directory) may also be useful.