# How to get css and images files from clojurescript application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clojure, clojurescript, reagent

I wrote a `clojurescript` project. It is a reagent component. This is a continuation of my previous question:
[How to use common dependencies in different clojurescript projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422128/how-to-use-common-dependencies-in-different-clojurescript-projects)

I require my `cljs` project (project A) from another project (project B)
through the `:dependencies` in a project.clj file. I work at the project B and require the reagent component from the project A. Then when I compile the project B to .jar I get the reagent component working correct, all styles are included. But when I compile `cljs` files to js project A styles are not included.

My question is how can I compile my `cljs` project B to js files and save styles and other static files from project A? I use a lein-cljsbuild plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar situation takes place with the re-com library: https://github.com/Day8/re-com#using-re-com

They advice just place css and other asset files to a folder manually, then include it from the index.html